# Internet service provider locator

Tags: java, android, function

Is there any function that can get your Internet service provider information?

In other words, when you're connected to Wi-Fi at any place or even 3G; can you get the ISP of the network you're connected to (example IDM, terranet, cyberia etc..) via a function (i goggled NETWORK_PROVIDER but can it do this).

My Plan B was to trace every provider in my country and analyze results; but if there's a function that can get such info's that would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

See `TelephonyManager` class for this purpose. This class Provides access to information about the telephony services on the device. Applications can use the methods in this class to determine telephony services and states, as well as to access some types of subscriber information. Applications can also register a listener to receive notification of telephony state changes.

[Developers Android Site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html)

This methods are of your use

```
public String getNetworkOperatorName ()
public String getSimOperatorName ()
```